# by.buttonText('') does not return empty texted buttons as protractor locator

Tags: javascript, testing, datepicker, automation, protractor

I have to test an application that has some buttons with no text, only graphics (these are `<` and `>` buttons on a datepicker, for instance, not in my control).

If I try to find these by:

```
elm = element.all(by.buttonText(''));
backButton = elm.get(1);
```

I get no immediate error, but if I say `backButton.click()` I get:

```
Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.buttonText("").
```

On the other hand if I say

```
element.all(by.tagName("BUTTON")).filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {

        //find the empties
        return !(text);
        //
    });
}).then(function (EmptyButtons) {

    EmptyButtons[1].click()
```

I get a fun error suggesting I found one that I clicked did not pop up yet:

> JavascriptError: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated (status: 11)

but that is on me to figure out. If I track the text as it comes through the filter, I find there are multiple text-less buttons placed in the array.

I am sorry I do not yet have the skills to generate and test a small example, but I hope perhaps some helpful reader does.
Anyway, I suppose it is possible I am missing something subtle about promise resolution or that the desired behavior is you cannot find a textless button by looking for empty text. I have a workaround, too (actually multiple ones - see my comment below). But I would welcome some clarification here if someone can give it.
Best,
Jeremy Kahan
p.s. I do not see this as a duplicate of "How to click a button with no text in protractor" inasmuch as that wrestles with distinguishing textless buttons, and my question is not how to find and distinguish them, but why searching for text '' does not find them. [My code even suggests how that could have been or could still be implemented, I think.]

Comment: So in some deeper sense, I think the right workaround in this particular case is:    backButton=element(by.css("span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left"));
                            forwardButton=element(by.css("span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right"));

Comment: A better solution is to not test third party software. You don't have to click buttons on a date picker, just put the date value in the input field. The field is software that's part of the application you're testing: the date picker widget is part of a toolkit that you're not testing (and your boss isn't paying you to test).

Comment: Paul, that is what I did until I was testing on iOS for iPAD, where the date control won't let me use SendKeys, because the keyboard does not come up for date fields.

Comment: Ouch. Wouldn't have thought the keyboard was important for that, but there you go. How about setting the value of the form field directly? Or calling whatever javascript the date control uses for setting the date? The aim is to avoid becoming beholden to the UI, and stick to testing the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have good workarounds and ways to solve the problem without using `by.buttonText` and only need an explanation why `by.buttonText('')` does not work.

If we look into [how the `by.buttonText` is implemented,](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/71532f055c720b533fbf9dab2b3100b657966da6/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L511) we would see it first finds only the following "button" variations:

```
button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]
```

Which means that *if the element you are looking for is not the `button` or appropriate `input` element, you would not get it matched by the locator*.

And, judging by the workaround, the desired elements in your case are actually `span` elements.

Aside, from that, matching by the empty "button text" should work.

---

Tested on the datepicker used in our internal application under test - worked for me. Here is how the "<" button looks in our case:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1" ap-tab-nav-idx="1.2" ap-tab-nav-child="true">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
</button>
```

And, if I mimic the "by.buttonText" client side script logic in the console, I would get this element passing all the conditions which determine whether to pick an element or not:

```
> var element = $("button[ng-click='move(-1)']")[0]
> elementText = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
> elementText.trim() === ""
true
```

Comment: thanks @alecxe and Paul. I now believe the by.buttonText('') would work. After seeing the my glyphicon idea failed (I think it is not a span, and it is almost for sure a button), I discovered that what is actually happening is that the elements disappear when anything else gets clicked on, and do not reappear for a little while. I found that out because I simplified and got < (th[0]) and > (th[2]) by TagName 'th' and they were there in the filter and gone after I clicked on the Year and Date (th[1]) in between them (0 elements matching 'th'). I am now taking Paul's first advice and moving on.